# Apache server redirect

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect my website's www to non-www.

I found an article with this code spinet for my site's Apache config file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The problem is that it will redirect and end up  being  https://yourdomain.com//  or https://yourdomain.com//page.php (2 slashes).

When i remove the  / before the $1 it redirects  to https://yourdomain.compage.php which also is no good.

Any help is appreciated.
Other methods of this also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The double slashes your Redirect path is getting because your `(.*)` regex captures the leading slash from your url path and your `$1` adds it to the target  `https://yourdomain.com/$1` .

To fix this you can either make the trailing slash  optional  in your regex , (change your pattern to `^/?(.*)$` ) or remove the trailing slash before `$1` ie . `https://yourdomain.com$1` .

Make sure to clear your browser cache before doing this change.